# Aggregate messages without List

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration and I need to pack group of messages by 10k. I don't want to store it into List since later 10k could became much bigger and persistent storage is also not my choice. I just want that several threads send messages into single thread where I can count them and write into disk into files containing 10k lines. After counter reaches 10k I create new file set counter to zero and so on. It would work fine with direct channel but how to tell several threads(I'm using

```
  <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
```

) to send messages into single thread? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach the task with the `QueueChannel`. Any threads can send messages to it concurrently. On the other side you should just configure `PollingConsumer` with the `fixed-delay` poller - single-threaded, as you requested. I mean that poller with the `fixed-delay` and everything downstream with the `DirectChannel` will be done only in single thread. Therefore your count and rollover logic can be reached there.

Nothing to show you, because that configuration is straight forward: different services send messages to the same `QueueChannel`. The `fixed-delay` poller ensures single-threaded reading for you.

Comment: thanks for answer, but isn't fixed-delay delays receiving of every messages i.e. even if i set fixed-delay=10 every message will be polled with delay 10 ms? I have a lot of data and I need to handle it as fast as possible. I was wondering about AtomicIntegerCounter. This should work in multithreadded environment since beans are singletone per application context, isn't it?

Comment: oh, i realised that i can set delay=0. So I believe is what I need, thanks